# WordPress cache on the backend side

Tags: wordpress, apache, caching, nginx

I have the same problem on different WordPress based websites.

I developed some of them, while others are made by someone else.
They don't have that much in common: completely different websites, different themes/plugins and so on.

Recently in these websites, I've been experiencing this problem: WordPress is caching the backend in a really tough way and, after saving any edits, I have to force a refresh with ctrl+f5 to actually see the edits I made before.
After some digging I can assure that:

- it doesn't seem to depend on the webserver (same problem on nginx and on apache)
- it doesn't depend on varnish or wp caching plugins (it happens also on website without any cache solutions)
- it happens just in some new wp releases, I'm not experiencing this problem on older websites
- it doesn't depend on my pc/browser configuration because my colleagues are experiencing the exact same problem on their pc

Anyone who had the same problem and was able to find a solution?

EDIT: It actually happened also on a fresh WordPress installation. Once I created a page, I went back to the page list by clicking on the menu item and I couldn't see the page in the list. After forcing a page refresh the newly created page was there as it was supposed to be before.

Comment: using cloud like Cloudflare ?

Comment: no, no Cloudflare or any other cdn at all...

Comment: You'd need to explain a lot more about the infrastructure behind each site, which parts are consistent and what you have looked at yourself to eliminate as potential bottlenecks.

Comment: Breeze is a cache plugin that offers the most complete set of functionality for all your WordPress cache management requirements. At the time of this email, it has 20,000+ active installs and the number is rising rapidly. It provides all industry-standard functionalities, completely FOR FREE.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/breeze/